# Can't use NDB get_by_id to get entity in namespace

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I'd like to read outside the current namespace with something like the following:

```
some_entity = MyModel.get_by_id(some_id_name, namespace='somenamespace')
```

but get_by_id doesn't take namespace as a parameter. I get:

```
TypeError: Unknown configuration option ('namespace')
```

I've gotten things to work with:

```
some_entity = ndb.Key(MyModel, some_id_name, namespace='somenamespace').get()
```

So now I'm just complaining, but I figured others could benefit from this. :) Also, since Guido monitors this, is there a reason for not allowing the namespace option in get_by_id?

**EDIT:** [This is now possible in App Engine 1.7.0.](http://hilinkit.appspot.com/ye4cmq)

Comment: release: "1.8.3" and it still throws the same error :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please file a feature request in the NDB issue tracker: http://code.google.com/p/appengine-ndb-experiment/issues/list

Comment: Note that this was fixed long ago. :-)

Answer (score 0):

you could first change the namespace and then you get the entity by_id

```
from google.appengine.api import namespace_manager

namespace_manager.set_namespace('thenamespace')
MyModel.get_by_id(some_id_name)
```

Comment: does not this will set the namespace globally and effect other db calls too ?

Comment: yes it will. you are changing the namespace and it will stay in that namespace until you set it back. you can use `namespace_manager.get_namespace()` to store the originary namespace in a variable and set it back to that namespace after the query is done.

Comment: i would say that it depends on your code. the namespace is changed within your code/request not for the app globally.

Comment: In what way is this a better solution than the last code entry listed in the question?

Comment: i don't think this is a better solution. its another way of doing the same thing.